# I seek clarifications about working with APIs

Tags: python, api

The following code is from the *Python Crash Course* book. **Chapter 17**: *Working with APIs*.
Brief description: in the code below the Author requests data by using API CALL (Github's API, to be exact), sets the URL as a variable, sets a header, as well, as a variable, and more. This is all in a simple way to apply clickable/easy-to-understand to newcomers (to code).

```
import requests

# Make an API call and store the response
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=starts'
headers = {'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'} # What does this do?
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
print(f"status code {r.status_code}")

...extra code snipped...
```

Is the headers-variable always necessary? matter of fact, why having header-variable in the first place? I'll cite the explanation from the book below as a quote.

> GitHub is currently on the third version of its API, so we define
> headers for the API call 3[refers to headers-variable] that ask explicitly to use this version of
> the API.

Comment: Are you asking about the `requests` module or GitHub API specifically? Or are you asking what the purpose of HTTP headers are?

Comment: @E_Roj: It's documented in the [Github API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api)

Comment: In the code above, the Author has created a variable [headers]. I don't understand the purpose of that line solely! I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking 2 questions:

- What are HTTP headers
- What does the header named `accept` mean in the case of GitHub API.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) you can read (in general) about HTTP headers.

As for the second question:

> The Accept request HTTP header advertises which content types, expressed as MIME types, the client is able to understand. Using content negotiation, the server then selects one of the proposals, uses it and informs the client of its choice with the Content-Type response header.

For an exact explanation for the specific header value see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/media-types).

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) for more .